# MySQL dump with special charactered table name

Tags: mysql, cmd, character-encoding, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a dump file with mysqldump.exe

I tried it like this:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE>mysqldump --column-statistics=0 --single-transaction -p3306 -h10.10.10.10 -u username -p dbName > backup.sql
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Enter password: ****************
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW CREATE TABLE `PLZ_Stra├ƒen`': Table 'dbName.PLZ_Stra├â┼©en' doesn't exist (1146)
```

Because of the special character, the dump process fails, How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to specify the character set with `--default-character-set=utf8mb4` option when using mysqldump

```
mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8mb4 --column-statistics=0 --single-transaction -p3306 -h10.10.10.10 -u username -p dbName > backup.sql
```

or you can set any character set in mysql using that

Answer (score 1):

`├ƒ`, when interpreted as `CHARACTER SET cp850` is hex c39f.

`ß`, which is presumably the character you wanted, when interpreted as `CHARACTER SET utf8` (or utf8mb4) is hex c39f.

One hand is talking cp850; the other hand is utf8.  Be consistent.

You seem to be using the Windows `cmd`.  The command `chcp 65001` provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed.